# Azure Data Lake Gen 2 & Python copying files within Data Lake folders

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

Using the samples proved here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=account-key.   I have been able to connect to my Azure Data Lake instance and peruse the directory/file structure. Do some simple operations. All good.
Next step: I have load up a large file into the data lake.
Issue: I need two copies of the file in the data lake, one is the As-Received copy and the second may get modified.  Want avoid loading the file twice.
Was hoping I could load the file once and then copy to the second location.
In the above samples I see how to upload a file,  move a file & how to delete a file, but no copy a file.

Your kind assistance is requested.

KD

---

** New CODE  ** New Attempt  ** New Exception **
revised my coded based on Googling and browsing

```
import datetime 
import time
import os, uuid
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob  import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.storage.blob import ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions, BlobSasPermissions
from azure.storage.blob import generate_account_sas , generate_blob_sas
import  azure.core.exceptions


storage_account_name = "XXdatarepos"
storage_account_key = "qvoVHq5NP9EtzKcmH1mm9kXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX**XX**XXAStWgFLpA=="
container_name = "iadata"
local_dir_name  = "C:\XXX\SupplierManagement"
target_dir_name = "Inbox/Test/"
target_dir_name2 = "Repos/SupplierXXX/Data/fooMar9/"
file_name =   "compare_all.xlsx"
local_filePath = os.path.join(local_dir_name, file_name)

target_blob = target_dir_name  +  file_name
target_blob2 = target_dir_name2  +  file_name

account_url = "https://"+ storage_account_name + ".blob.core.windows.net"

# Create the BlobServiceClient object
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=storage_account_key,   connection_verify= False)
containers = blob_service_client.list_containers( name_starts_with="iadata" , include_metadata=True)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("iadata")   
cc_url  = container_client.url

# Create sas token for blob
sas_resource_types=ResourceTypes(service=True, object=True, container=True)
try:
    sas_token_target = generate_account_sas(  account_name = blob_service_client.account_name, 
                       container_name=container_client.container_name,  
                       account_key = storage_account_key ,  
                       blob_name=target_blob, 
                       resource_types = sas_resource_types,
                       permission= AccountSasPermissions(read=True) ,   expiry = datetime.timedelta(hours=4)  )
except Exception as error:
    print(error)    
    print( type(error).__name__ )
    
    


source_blob_client = BlobClient(account_url = account_url, container_name= container_client.container_name,  blob_name=target_blob, credential = sas_token_target   )
##  ##  source_blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(target_blob )
##  ##  source_blob_client = BlobClient(account_url = cc_url, blob_name=target_blob, credential = sas_token_target   )

target_blob_client =   container_client.get_blob_client(target_blob2)

target_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url, requires_sync=True)

copy_properties = target_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy

if copy_properties.status != "success":
    target_blob_client.abort_copy(copy_properties.id)
    raise Exception(
            f"Unable to copy blob %s with status %s"
            % (target_blob, copy_properties.status)
    )
```

** ** New Exception ** **
The warning about InsecureRequestWarning is new

```
ipdb> C:\Users\ne098406\.conda\envs\python_3.7_XXX\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:3d2343a2-001e-00a6-5d2c-7ae40b000000
Time:2024-03-19T18:40:46.7150943Z
ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:3d2343a2-001e-00a6-5d2c-7ae40b000000
Time:2024-03-19T18:40:46.7150943Z</Message></Error>
None
> c:\kbd\testazure\testblobcopymar18.py(57)<module>()
     55 target_blob_client =   container_client.get_blob_client(target_blob2)
     56 
---> 57 target_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url, requires_sync=True)
     58 
     59 copy_properties = target_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy


ipdb> --Return--
None
> c:\kbd\testazure\testblobcopymar18.py(57)<module>()
     55 target_blob_client =   container_client.get_blob_client(target_blob2)
     56 
---> 57 target_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(source_blob_client.url, requires_sync=True)
     58 
     59 copy_properties = target_blob_client.get_blob_properties().copy
```

The source_blob_client.url  is below

```
ipdb> 
ipdb> source_blob_client.url
'https://iadatarepos.blob.core.windows.net/iadata/Inbox/Test/compare_all.xlsx?se=4%3A00%3A00&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&ss=b&srt=sco&sig=an0cyq5YK%2BL0woSLQIUzWUoz9V1GbHHQyJnOQipxDCI%3D'
```

If I put this URL into Chrome (without the single quotes)  I get

`AuthenticationFailed`
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:4f30a97b-801e-003e-75cd-7ac46a000000 Time:2024-03-20T13:53:05.9201944Z
Signature fields not well formed.

Your kind assistance requested.

KBD

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to copy the file from one directory to another directory in ADLS Gen2 using python:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def copy_files_to_adls(account_url, sas_token, source_container, source_directory, destination_container, destination_directory):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=sas_token) 
    source_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(source_container)
    blobs = source_container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=source_directory) 
    for blob in blobs:
        source_blob_path = "<sourcePath>"
        destination_blob_path = "<destinationDirectory>/<fileName>"
        blob_service_client.get_blob_client(destination_container, destination_blob_path).start_copy_from_url(source_blob_path)    
    print("Files copied successfully!")


account_url = 'https://adlsc.blob.core.windows.net'
account_name = '<accountname>'
account_key = "<accountKey>"
source_container = '<sourceContainer>'
source_directory = '<sourceDirectory>'
destination_container = '<destinationContainer>'
destination_directory = '<destinationDirectory>'

copy_files_to_adls(account_url, account_key, source_container, source_directory, destination_container, destination_directory)
```

[image]

The file is copied successfully with same name.

[image]

Comment: Interesting you are not using the azure.storage.filedatalake objects as per the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=account-key.    Should I be using the azure.storage.blob objects?   Want to avoid painting myself into a corner.     Thanks for your swift response.  KD

Comment: Yes you can use azure.storage.blob objects for datalake gen2 account files.

Comment: OK looks like I should be using azure.storage.blob objects.   The call for blob_service_client.get_blob_client is cut off above, can you provide the full code.

Comment: -Or- Maybe the this example covers it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175743/how-to-copy-a-blob-from-one-container-to-another-container-using-azure-blob-stor

Comment: Apologies for not reverting promptly , but the above code is cut off.  Neebee here need the complete code.   Thanks  KD

Comment: I tried this code based on the suggestion above:

Comment: Just read through the postings, there is no solution here that I can get to work.

Comment: Above provided code will copy files from one directory to another directory in storage account successfully without any issue. Can I get your requirement?