# unable to copy blob in Azure using start_copy_from_url

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm tryng to copy a blob from one container to a subfolder in the same container but i have been unable to do so. I'm using Python Azure SDK 12 and using the example provided here and in many other places as base https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285413

```
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_connection_str)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("mycontainer")
    source_blob = container_client.get_blob_client("mycontainer", "myblob.txt")
    destination_blob = container_client.get_blob_client("mycontainer", "subfolder/myblob.txt")

    destination_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
```

However when i ran the last line it'd fail saying that snapshot is an invalid queryParam, and i printed out souce_blob.url and it was indeed not the url i would have expected

`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/mycontainer?snapshot=/mycontainer/subfolder/myblob.txt`

So I tried constructing the url myself manually as in this example, this URL is the exact same URL i get when i go to Azure portal to get the URL for the blob: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401832

```
    source_blob = (f"https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/subfolder/myblob.txt")
    destination_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob)
```

but for some reason i still get the same snapshot error, i don't understand why `start_copy_from_url` is passing the blob name as a snapshot param? i'm very confused by that

`ErrorCode:InvalidQueryParameterValue Error:None QueryParameterName:snapshot QueryParameterValue:mycontainer/subfolder/myblob.txt`

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong or how to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Python but once you are specifying the container name **mycontainer** in line nr 2, why do you specify it again in lines 3 and 4? Check it here [get_blob_client for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#get-blob-client-blob--snapshot-none-)

The code should be(lines 3 and 4)

```
source_blob = container_client.get_blob_client("myblob.txt")
destination_blob = container_client.get_blob_client("subfolder/myblob.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's because it's two different clients, however i did change the code as suggested but still getting same error, no difference.